# How to disable and gray out a textbox based on dropdownlist selection using OnSelectedIndexChanged

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I need to disable (read only) a textbox and grey it out based on dropdown list selection using OnSelectedIndexChanged. I tried with the following code but it didn't work and I was still able to write in the textbox.

This the html:

```
       <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"
           Width="144px" Height="19px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_SelectedIndexChanged">
              <asp:ListItem Text="--Select--" Value="0" />
              <asp:ListItem Text="New York" Value= "1" />
              <asp:ListItem Text="Brooklyn" Value= "2" />
       </asp:DropDownList>



               <table>
                  <tr>
                       <td>New York:</td>
                        <td>
                          <asp:TextBox ID="txt_NY" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" />
                        </td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                        <td>Brooklyn:</td>
                        <td>
                          <asp:TextBox ID="txt_Brooklyn" runat="server"AutoPostBack="true"/>
                        </td>
                   </tr>
               </table>
```

This is my code:

```
 protected void ddl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
       if (ddl.SelectedItem.Value == "1")
         {

            txt_Brooklyn.Enabled = false;

            txt_Brooklyn.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
         }

     }
```

Comment: Would you please edit your question and add a specific question?  You've told us what you want to do, but you haven't told us what problem you're facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `ReadOnly` property, this way it automatically greys out

```
protected void ddl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
           if (ddl.SelectedItem.Value == "1")
           {
                txt_NY.ReadOnly = false; //set to false to make it editable
                txt_Brooklyn.ReadOnly = true; //true to grey out
           }

           elseif (ddl.SelectedItem.Value == "2")
           {
                txt_Brooklyn.ReadOnly = false;
                txt_NY.ReadOnly = true;
           }

    }
```

Comment: it works with readonly and backcolor set to gray but when I select Brooklyn both textboxes become readonly and gray. How can I refresh the page when the dropdownlist selection changes?